# Struct casting behavior different between for and foreach loops

Tags: c#

I came across this bizarre situation just now: I was editing some legacy code which looks something like this:

```
Hashtable hashtable = GetHashtable();

for (int i = 0; i < hashtable.Count; i++)
{
    MyStruct myStruct = (MyStruct)hashtable[i];

    //more code
}
```

Now when changing this to a `foreach` loop:

```
var hashtable = GetHashtable();

foreach (var item in hashtable)
{
    var myStruct = (MyStruct)item;

    //more code
}
```

I had assumed the behavior would be the same, however, I get `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`

What is the reason for this different behavior?

Comment: @CédricBignon: it's good old "legacy code"

Comment: Just as a side note - the legacy code is much uglier than I posted... I just didn't have the heart to subject SO to lower case struct and method names, etc.

Comment: If you have Resharper, you can put your cursor on the `var` keyword and select "Specify type explicitly" to see what you're really dealing with.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Iterating a `Hashtable` doesn't iterate its values, rather it iterates key value pairs as a [`DictionaryEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object.

Instead try iterating on its `.Values` collection instead.

```
foreach (var item in hashtable.Values)
{
    var myStruct = (MyStruct)item;
}
```

Since you are refactoring old legacy code, if possible, you should also consider using the generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead. It will take advantage of `struct` value semantics and avoid boxing.

---

If you wanted to iterate on the `DictionaryEntry` objects, you can do so but will need to cast to it as well as your `MyStruct`:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hashtable)
{
    var myStruct = (MyStruct)entry.Value;
}
```

---

Finally, there's the Linq solution, but it may not be applicable for you since this is legacy code; it may not be available:

```
foreach(var myStruct in hashtable.Values.Cast<MyStruct>())
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each yielded item in a Hashtable is a DictionaryEntry. Therefore you can also do it like this

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry de in hashtable)
{
    var myStruct = (MyStruct)de.Value;
    //more code
}
```